# How to pass 2 arguments from template to views in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, url, view

So I know I can pass one argument like this: {%url '...path...' argument%} but I want to pass 2 arguments like {%url '...path...' argument1 argument2%}
Here is my exact code:
search.html:

```
{% for id, title, thumbnail in videos%}
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{id}}"><img src="{{thumbnail}}">{{title}}</a><p style="display:inline;">   |   </p><a href="{%url 'select' id title%}">Add to playlist</a>
    <br>
{%endfor%}
```

urls.py:

```
path('select/<id>/<title>', views.select, name='select'),
```

I get the following error: 
Reverse for 'select' with arguments '('omPiA5AsGWw', 'PRESLAVA - POSLEDEN ADRES / Преслава - Последен адрес, 2007')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['select/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)$']

Comment: Your title contains a slash. You should specify `<path:title>`. Although that being said, I'm not sure it is a good idea to encode such titles in the url. You might want to look at `slug`s instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/glossary/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title contains a slash. You should specify `path` as *path converter*:

```
path('select/<id>/<path:title>', views.select, name='select'),
```

That being said, I'm not sure it is a good idea to encode such titles in the url, it will make ugly URLs with a lot of percentage encoded characters. You might want to look at [*slug*s instead [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to pass two paths but you could look at using condition tags in template to avoid a lot of hardcoded templates